# Como hago que la Barra lateral quede al lado de los articulos, me queda abajo de el footer

Tags: css

necesito ayuda con esto, no me queda la barra lateral al lado de los artículos. La primera foto es como me debe quedar, la segunda como me queda. Si necesitan mas detalles por favor no duden en preguntarme, necesito esto para hoy si pueden, gracias 1era foto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK6zl.jpg 2da foto: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oryPS.jpg

```
@charset "utf-8"
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font: bold 20px verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    font: bold 14px verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
    text-align:center;
}
#Encabezado {
    background: #fffbb9;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 20px;
}
aside {
    float: right;
    background: red;
}
article {
    background: #FFFBCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
article footer {
    text-align: right;
}
#Menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bold 14px verdana, sans-serif;
}
#Menu {
    background: #cccccc;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
#Seccion {
    width: 660px;
    margin: 20px;
}
#Lateral {
    background: #cccccc;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#Pie {
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta carece de información, debes proporcionar el html para tener una idea de como estás estructurando el contenido, te sugiero que elimines la letra mayuscula al inicio de todas las clases y ID, ya que no es correcto hacer eso en css ej. (#Encabezado) debe ser #encabezado.

Comment: Ten el html, lo pongo aca, está largo, te sirve así?https://www.miblocdenotas.com/361106

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba agregando esto a tu CSS

Veo que estás iniciando en esto, actualmente ya casi no se usa la propiedad float de css, lee un poco sobre el uso de la propiedad flexbox, no hay nada mejor de ser autodidacta, con ganas se aprende todo.

Y recuerda, elimina las mayúsculas al principio de cada clase/ID, en el css y en el html.

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font: bold 20px verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    font: bold 14px verdana, geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
    text-align:center;
}
#encabezado {
    background: #fffbb9;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 20px;
}
article {
    background: #FFFBCC;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
article footer {
    text-align: right;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 5px;
    font: bold 14px verdana, sans-serif;
}
#menu {
    background: #cccccc;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
#seccion {
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
}
#articles {
    width: 65%
}
#lateral {
    background: #cccccc;
    
    padding: 20px;
}
aside {
    width: 35%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#pie {
}
```

```html
    <div>
            <header id="encabezado">
                    <h1>Encabezado de la pagina web, elemento header</h1>
            </header>
            <nav id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Menu 1</li>
                    <li>Menu 2</li>
                    <li>Menu 3</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <section id="seccion">
                <div id="articles">
                    <article>
                        <h2>Titulo del primer articulo</h2>
                        <p>Contenido principal del <mark>articulo 1</mark></p>
                        <footer>
                            <small>Fin articulo 1</small>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                    <article>
                        <h2>Titulo del segundo articulo</h2>
                        <p>Este es el contenido principal del <mark>articulo 2</mark></p>
                        <footer>
                            <small>Fin articulo 2</small>
                        </footer>
                    </article>
                </div>

                <aside>
                    <div id="lateral">
                        
                    <div>
                        Elemento barra lateral <br> Uno <br> Dos <br> Tres <br>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </section>

            <footer id="pie">
                    Informacion de la empresa, elemento footer
            </footer>
    </div>
```

Comment: Entendido @BetaM, no volverá a pasar, con respecto a lo de flexbox, supongo que depende de quien lo interprete, al menos en mozilla lo tratan como propiedad flexbox (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Usando_las_cajas_flexibles_CSS)

Comment: ok @BetaM, leeré al respecto, gracias por la info.

Comment: No me funcionó, alguna otra persona que me pueda ayudar?

Comment: Supongo que no te funcionó porque estás usando alguna resolución menor, al bajar de cierta resolución, el tamaño de las cajas hace que el contenedor baje, esto es porque no estás usando diseño responsive, a mi me funciona, pero al bajar a los 1000px el contenedor se desplaza hacia abajo, por eso te recomendé usar flexbox, o en su defecto, trabajar el width de las cajas en porcentajes en lugar de pixeles.

Comment: Estas diciendo que te funciona, entonces, puedes pasarme el código que colocaste?

Comment: @Sam., el anterior funcionaba, acabo de editar mi respuesta y lo he colocado completo, eliminando los floats y colocando flexbox en su lugar, modificando anchos en pixeles y colocando en porcentajes.